# How to get propertyValue of an Array type?

Tags: testcomplete

I need to get the property value of a property that is of type "VBArray". In particular, I have made an array with the values that I expect that property to contain, and I want to compare this to the VBArray value of the property.

I am using TestComplete, so when I inspect the object, I can see that the property I want to check is of VBArray type.
I have tried using the getPropertyValue and CheckProperty functions, which do not work since they do not support Arrays. 
It is also not possible to access it by pointing to the indexes (it seems like it has no indexes).

The property shows as follows in Object Browser:

```
OleValue: [1,2,3,4,5]
Description - VBArray OleValue.
```

I want to read the value of the OleValue property and then compare it to my own array (I could also use a string, I am just trying to check that the value in the object is the expected one).

Something like:

```
function a(){
var expectedArray = new Array(1,2,3,4,5);
var observedArray = //Here lies my problem - how to get the VBArray value?

for (var i=0, i<x, i<++){
   expectedArray[i] == observedArray[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found out. 
The way is to call the property with .ToArray() after:
var observedArray = Property.OleValue.ToArray();